# ExecCGI turned off in this directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, python, mac, cgi

I'm trying to run a python cgi script on my Mac's web server. Everytime I visit the file @ localhost/site.py I get a 403 forbidden error.

I'm looking in my Apache's error log, and it says:

```
[Mon Jun 11 09:52:42 2012] [error] [client ::1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /Users/<username>/Sites/site.py
```

I've changed my httpd.conf file so that my document root is /Users//Sites

In my user's .conf file, I have the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/<username>/Sites/">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Why is it telling me ExecCGI is off, when I've allowed all options in my user's .conf file?

Comment: Are you sure it is fully contained in that directory and does not reference elements outside that directory?

Comment: yep! The only thing it does is print out 'hello world'

Answer (score 1):

Do you use mac's built-in apache2, or package like XAMPP?
I found XAMPP doesn't use user.conf, one have to edit /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf.

Another things is the change of user.conf take effect AFTER apache restart.